# ADL of class itself

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

According to standard argument dependent lookup adds to search set class if we have class type as function argument:

> If `T` is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are: the **class itself**; the class of which it is a member, if any; and its direct and indirect base classes.

If so why `foo` cannot be found in this context:

```
class X{
public:
void foo(const X& ref){std::cout<<"Inner class method\n";}
};

int main(){
X x;
foo(x);
}
```

Shouldn't adp add to search set `X` class and look for `foo` in there?

Comment: Your example would be better if you stuck a `static` on there.

Comment: Hmm good point static would not be assigned to class but call still fails??

Comment: @user3655463 Even if `foo` was `static` you still would have to call `X::foo(x);`

Comment: Ok, so still don't understand this part of snippet from standard "its associated classes are: the class itself; ".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because `foo` is a member function, not a free function which can be found through ADL.

Perhaps you means this:

```
static void foo(const X& ref){std::cout<<"Inner class method\n";}
```

This also would not be found through ADL; you would need to qualify the call like `X::foo(b)`.

The clauses about associated classes are for friend functions declared in a class. For example:

```
class X{
public:
    friend void foo(const X& ref){std::cout<<"Inner class method\n";}
};
```

`foo` is a non-member function, but it can only be found through ADL.

Comment: "The clauses about associated classes are for friend functions declared in a class", that answers my question

Answer (score 2):

`foo` isn't a free function, it is a class method so you need to call it from an instance of your class

```
X a;
X b;
a.foo(b);
```

Note that ADL is used here so you don't have to write out the following, which would also compile fine, but is unnecessarily verbose due to ADL

```
a.X::foo(b);
```

Comment: Is ADL really necessary for that example? `foo` is already scoped by `a`, regardless of the presence of `b`.